# Writing a mod-wsgi script on Amazon linux

Tags: mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

I am using `httpd2.4` with `mod-wsgi` installed on Amazon linux.

My `wsgi` script looks like this:

#### /projects/mv2/test/test.wsgi

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

from test import *
```

#### /projects/mv2/test/test.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

#### Apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test-algo.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess algos_app user=mv2 group=mv2 threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /projects/mv2/test/test.wsgi

    <Directory /projects/mv2/test/test>
        WSGIProcessGroup algos_app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Options MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I hit the url `http://test-algo.com/test`, I get a 403 response and the following the `httpd error file`

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 27555] [client 153.156.225.142:65083] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /projects/mv2/test/test.wgi
```

I am not able to find what is wrong with the `wsgi` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Directory` blog should start with:

```
<Directory /projects/mv2/test>
```

You have an extra `test` at end of path.

That would cause the 403 error.

The WSGI script should also use:

```
from test import app as application
```

The name of the WSGI entry point is expected to be `application` not `app` as your Flask file uses.

If don't fix this you will get a different error after fixing the first.

Comment: If I remove the extra test and write `<Directory /projects/mv2/test>`, I get the following error `[:error] [pid 29378] [client 153.156.225.142:54364] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /projects/mv2/test/test.wgi` . I also changed to `from test import app as application` in the WSGI script.

Comment: You also have the path in the ``WSGIScriptAlias`` directive wrong. You have ``/projects/mv2/test/test.wgi`` when should be ``/projects/mv2/test/test.wsgi``. Please check for obvious mistakes.